# How to customize fabric canvas with customize property

Tags: fabricjs

Good morning,everyone ,I have a problem that I want to pass an array of fabric json data to server, and load it back for after a while, since I have to load the details from canvas from multiple page pdf. It has to pass the canvas name as well.

problem here is if I use JSON.stringify(mycanvas);
it doesn't convert my customize attribute into json data. So I have to do something like inherit from the fabric canvas to extend the attribute.

I found some useful like to create custom text, custom image, I tried something similar to them, it just doesn't work. Please help me on this.

my code  :
code to create such customize canvas

```
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
create CustomCanvas class from Text class
fabric.CustomCanvas = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Canvas, {
type: 'custom-canvas',
initialize: function(element, options) {
    this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
    options && this.set('canvasname', options.canvasname);
},
toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), 
{canvasname: this.canvasname});
}
});    
fabric.CustomText.fromObject = function(object) {
return new fabric.canvasname(object`enter code here`);
};
fabric.canvasname.async = false;`enter code here`
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//and to create a new customize canvas

```
var canvas = new fabric.CustomCanvas();
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(src, function() { 
 canvas.renderAll();
});
canvas.canvasname=1111;
```

I will so appreciate it, if someone could help me on this.

Comment: Take a look at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fabricjs/JdUmkwEaaqk/7wBrbe0xs9oJ